# Convergence and absolute convergence of sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Examine if the series converge $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin^2(\frac{1}{n})$.

For which $a$$\in \mathbb{R^+}$ the series converge $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^a}?$$ Also for which $a$ the series converge absolute?

For the first i proved it with the integral test and i found $Si(2)-\sin^2(1)$. Can we find another test to prove its convergence?

For the second, $b_n$ is decreasing and positive. Also we need $\lim_{n\to∞} b_n=0$ for Leibniz criteria to work. So we get $a>2$

For the absolute convergence we take $|b_n|\leq \frac{n^2}{n^a}=\frac{1}{n^{a-2}}$ and so we get $a>3$.

Is this right or am i wrong?

Comment: You're wrong about the second question, try $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ it diverges but $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$

Comment: Also, why do you have $\sqrt{n^4+1}\leq n^2$, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first note that

$$\sin^2(\frac{1}{n})\sim \frac1{n^2}$$

For the second note that it is not an alternating series but it is strictly positive, a good method can be to observe that

$$\frac{\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^a}\sim \frac1{n^{a-2}}$$

then use [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

Comment: Giving an alternative proof does not answer the main question by the OP: "Is this right or am i wrong?" (I take it as "what is wrong, if anything, in my argument?")

Comment: @ClementC. You are right for the second, for the first he/she was asking for an alternative! I fix, Thanks

Comment: I don't get the second hint that you give. Why is this equivalent?

Comment: @argiriskar it is equivalent by definition since $$\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^a}}{ \frac1{n^{a-2}}}\to 1$$ then by limit comparison test the two series have the same behaviour, thus we can study the simpler  $\frac1{n^{a-2}}$.

Comment: @argiriskar Keep "limit comparison test" and "asymptotic equivalence" tools always with you for series! You are Welcome! Bye